# implement multiple slider instances through wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, smooth-scrolling

i have customised the smooth div scroll jquery plugin (http://smoothdivscroll.com/) and implemented it in wordpress as a wordpress plugin along with an options page you can view the slider here http://dev.linuxfreakz.com/?page_id=2 , i have created an options page in wordpress admin which has 4 options to select the slider title , background and arrows color and category of posts . the slides are wordpress posts and the images inside them are their featured images . the slider can be currently used with a shortcode , this is all fine and working .

the problem is that now i am supposed to add multiple sliders that can have different options selected and can be used on a single page through the options page and i am confused as how to get this done . can some wordpress guru please point me in the right direction i am really running out of time here , i don't need the whole code just an idea as how i could actually get this done and i am pretty good at php and wordpress myself usually .

any help would be appreciated , thank you .

here is the code that pulls the posts and generates the slider that i am currently using

```
function sds_display_slider() {
  global $post;

      $sds_category2 = (get_option('sds_category') != false) ? get_option('sds_category') : 1;

      $sds_title2 = (get_option('sds_title') != '') ? get_option('sds_title') : 'Smooth Slider';

      $sds_bgcolor2 = (get_option('sds_bgcolor') != '') ? get_option('sds_bgcolor') : '#dedede';

      $sds_navcolor2  = (get_option('sds_navcolor') != '') ? get_option('sds_navcolor') : '#9e1b32' ;   

      $plugins_url = plugins_url();

      echo '<div id="carousel" style="background-color:'.$sds_bgcolor2.'!important;">
    <style>
        div.scrollingHotSpotLeft {background-color:'.$sds_navcolor2.';}
        div.scrollingHotSpotRight{background-color:'.$sds_navcolor2.';}
    </style>
    <h2>'.$sds_title2.'</h2>
    <div id="makeMeScrollable">';

              query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1&cat='.$sds_category2.'&order=ASC');
        if ( have_posts() ) :while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

         $img_attached_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
        $img_attached = $img_attached_url[0];
        $post_heading = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $post_text = substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,180)."...";
        $link = get_permalink($post->ID);

        echo '<div class="contentBox">
            <a href="'.$link.'">
            <img src="'.$img_attached.'"></a><br>
            <a href="'.$link.'"><h2>'.$post_heading.'</h2></a>
            <p>'.$post_text.'</p>
        </div>'; 

        endwhile;

       endif;wp_reset_query();

    echo '</div>
  </div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Can you have it pull custom post types? Giving it a custom loop per page? I would think something just like this already exists?

Comment: you mean create a custom post type to save the settings for each slider ? i currently am not using custom posts i pull the normal posts with a custom loop by supplying a category id to it @BenRacicot

Comment: I've got it. What about putting your options page data in a meta box on the post edit page? Then that post will have your slider options  saved within its post meta.

Comment: yes that could be possible but i was thinking more like a gallery on options page which shows a list of sliders and edit link as well, i think i've seen that before too will try to look for a plugin for similar code . thanks for the advice btw @BenRacicot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/ and put your options page inside.

Comment: Awesome good luck, if you could mark mine as the best answer. :) Thanks again